# How to catch last row edit event in extjs3 grid

Tags: extjs, extjs3, extjs-grid

I have ExtJs grid, i want to keep empty editable row as last low in the grid. So when something typing on last row i want to add another empty last row the grid(when start typing/editing last row). but i can't catch last row istyping/isediting event.

```
this.mygrid.on('isLastrowtyping',function(){
   //this.addEmptyLastrow();
   }),this);
```

Is there any event as "isLastrowtyping" in ExtJs3 if not how can i catch this event using ExtJs

Answer (score 0):

You should add event handler in editor of your grid:

```
editor.on('afteredit',
    function(e){
                if (e.row==e.grid.store.data.length)
                {e.grid.store.data.add(%%youremptyrow%%)}   
                }),this);
```